# Identify specific image view from multiple imageviews

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uiimageview

I have a single image view, and I set other image views on it and put them in different locations. I want to apply FLIP ANIMATION on mage view. How can do it? when if(i==1) then my imageview is flipped. `img1` is my image view and I want to identify it. I allocate 52 images in `imagearr

My code:

```
-(void)setCards
{

    int k=0;
    CGFloat dx = self.view.frame.size.width/2;
    CGFloat dy = self.view.frame.size.height/2;

    int cnt = [imagearr count];


    for (int j=1; j<3; j++)            // Number of cards
    {
        for (int i=1; i<5; i++)         // Number of players
        {
            int rnd = (arc4random() % cnt)-1;   
            UIImage *img = [imagearr objectAtIndex:rnd];
            UIImageView *img1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];

            CGRect frame = img1.frame;
            frame.size.width = frameX;
            frame.size.height = frameY;
            [img1 setFrame:frame];
            [img1 setTag:k+i];

            [UIView beginAnimations:@"Move" context:nil];
            [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.50];
            if (i==1)
            {
                [img1 setCenter:CGPointMake(dx+100, dy+(j*15))];

            }
            if (i==2) 
            {
                [img1 setCenter:CGPointMake(dx+(j*15), dy+60)];
            }
            if (i==3) 
            {
                [img1 setCenter:CGPointMake(dx-130, dy-(j*15))];
            }
            if (i==4) 
            {
                [img1 setCenter:CGPointMake(dx-(j*20), dy-95)];
            }

            [self.view addSubview:img1];
            [UIView commitAnimations];
            [img1 release];

        }
        k=k+10;      
    }


}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{ 
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    int t = [touch view].tag;


}
```

I still can't identify a specific imageview. Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Re-asking the same question isn't acceptable behavior here.  If you want to draw attention to your question, you will be allowed to [place a bounty on it](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty) after two days.  You can also [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5854016/edit) to add additional information, which may make your question easier to understand and answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should take a look at the Apple sample project [GeekGameBoard](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/GeekGameBoard/Introduction/Intro.html). It implements a solitaire game and you will be able to learn how to select `CALayer`s* representing cards, drag them around, and have them interact with each other.

---

*Which will be both easier and probably better from a performance perspective than using views.

Answer (score 2):

Setting tag for individual imageView is the best approach. Using tag you could even detect multiples images placed inside tableview cells and set action for selection of individual tag as well.

Answer (score 0):

Associate a unique tag values with each **UIImageView** instances.

**Code for reference.**

```
myImageView1.tag = 1;
myImageView1.tag = 2;
myImageView1.tag = 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

Apple Link For the code:
[Detect imageview from multiple imageview](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Touches/Introduction/Intro.html)

Stack Link As Well
[Here is the discussion for to detect the images from the multiple images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739496/detecting-touches-on-multiple-uiimageviews)

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

There will be different images in different imageView so each imageView will be on different position.

in your touch method do you have to check the bounds of the touch and then you have to match which imageView lies under your touch region.According to that you can proceed your functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably place a **invisible UIbutton** over your imageviews and capture touch event. The effect is the same and its much more cleaner and simpler. Let me know if you need more info. Would be happy to edit my answer here.

Comment: thanks for reply but i want to make specific touch on imageview so i want properly do it...

Comment: Yes you cover your image view with a invisible button and you can use a tag or write specific callbacks to get the touch event. I have read about it and its highly recommended practice. Will try to post the relevant links here.

Answer (score 0):

you could try something similar to this

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event //here enable the touch       
{
    // get touch event      
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    int t = [touch view].tag;
    UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *) [self.view  viewWithTag:t];

    //your logic here
}
```